# Microsoft office Interop Excel V.S. Microsoft Excel Object Library

Tags: c#, excel, com-interop, excel-interop

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and trying to automate excel 365 from C#, I believe I'm suppose to add "Microsoft office interop excel" to the reference under the Framework/Assemblies, however, there was no option for me to select. I was told that I can also use "Microsoft Excel Object library" under COM. What is the difference between these two? and what do I have to do to install "Microsoft office interop excel"?

Comment: You need [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) and forget about headaches with interop

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Excel Interop library
[image: Done in VS2015]

**EDIT**
Open Object browser in Visual Studio. In the Browse combo box select "Custom Component Set" now click on the three dots.

[image]

Now traverse the dialog for Excel, if it's listed select the one you want (if more than one) and press the add button.
[image]

Now to add the reference to your project
[image]

Ending note: At my work place in VS2015 Excel library shows in the first dialog I mentioned but not at home so I needed to follow the steps laid out above several years ago.

Hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: It's not listed there, that's why posted this question

Comment: I added a second option to my original post. If you have the libraries installed this is how to do it and if the libraries are not installed you need to install them.

Comment: do you know what's the different between office interop excel and excel object library?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to connect with **Excel available at Office 365**. It is different from desktop Ms-Office Excel version.
For **Office 365** you have to connect to **Azure**. Refer the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/setup-development-environment) to set up the development environment.

Microsoft Graph API is what you need to try. Refer the [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office365/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=Technology&f%5B0%5D.Value=Office%20365&f%5B1%5D.Type=ProgrammingLanguage&f%5B1%5D.Value=C%23&f%5B1%5D.Text=C%23&pageIndex=1) for code samples for Office 365.